# Wifi not working after installing Ubuntu 15.10 on Toshiba Satellite S50-B-15N

Tags: wireless, toshiba, rfkill

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite S50-B-15N laptop to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 15.10 for the very first time today and unfortunately the wifi doesn't appear to be working. It works fine on Windows 10 though.

I am unable to enable wifi, likely due to there being no driver available? I can however connect an ethernet cable and connect to the internet that way. I did a little bit of googling and a few people mentioned going into 'additional drivers' in software and updates, but there was no wifi driver listed there.

Apologies as I'm new to Ubuntu, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: 
After entering `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` I get the following message:

```
Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev cb)
```

EDIT 2:
After entering `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 08B3` I get the following message:
[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pb36.png)

EDIT 3:
Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`, `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` and `uname -a`
[Terminal Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHx8o.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of the following terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Okay, I've made the edit, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Toby95 You missed `-A2`

Comment: When adding the `-A2` the terminal doesn't return anything

Comment: Also add: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 08B3` It may be blank but we need to know either way.

Comment: I've made a second edit

Comment: Please post output of the full `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` command and also `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` and `uname -a` and `rfkill list`

Comment: Made another edit, only just noticed the `rfkill list` one, I'll do that now quickly

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. You can copy text from terminal.

Comment: It is already clear that the problem is in rfkill.

Comment: Sorry, I am saving the screenshots to a USB and uploading them from my desktop PC because I don't have an internet connection on my Ubuntu laptop right now and it was a lot to type out.

Comment: You can copy text to USB as well. You see that your wireless adapter is hard blocked? It means that there is somewhere a hardware switch that blocks the wifi. Or it is disabled in bios.

Comment: There is a physical wifi on/off switch on my keyboard but it doesn't do anything if I press it. I have just checked the BIOS (which is very minimalistic in terms of options) and nothing there relates to wireless connectivity unfortunately.

Comment: Reset it to defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to find a hardware switch, then try to press Fn+F8 buttons to enable wifi.

Reset bios to default settings, then power off the laptop and remove the battery for some time.

If nothing of that works, try this solution:

On Toshiba Satellite laptop, start from powered off state.

Laptop battery can remain in the laptop (it is not removeable anyway easily in case of this model). AC adapter can remain plugged.

Push the power button and keep it pressed. The laptop will not power up until power button is held pushed.

After about 10 seconds the white LED showing that the AC adapter is connected properly is goes off and blinks once.

After this the white LED is on again. The power button was kept pushed until 30 seconds is elapsed (but I'm not sure if it is needed at all, the blink of the white LED seems to be a good feedback.)

When the power button is released the laptop keeps turned off. Pushing the power button again shortly starts the laptop and the following BIOS message appears:

```
**** RTC battery is low ****
Press Enter to set Date/Time.
[Enter]
```

After this BIOS Setup appears ("TOSHIBA Setup Utility") and System Time starts from 00:00:00, System Date starts from 01/01/2014. Set the time and date manually and then boot Ubuntu. The `rfkill list` shows now `Hard blocked: no`

```
root@ubuntu:~# rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1528009/comments/2

Comment: Success! After removing the battery for a few minutes and plugging it back in the BIOS told me to enter the date and time like your solution said (without having to do the power button phase). The wifi is now working fine!

Comment: OK. I will return the first solution and keep the last one in case the first does not work.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I appreciate you giving up your time